# How to use postman's aws-signature(using aws-iot rest api) into android application?

Tags: android, okhttp, aws-iot

1. Now i need to get thing shadow from aws-iot api.so when i hit same request into postman got 200ok in response.
2. From the app-side i got 403 i.e.forbidden.
3. Here i used "okhttp client" for fetch the request.

also attached image where i got 200ok response.

[image: get thing shadow from aws-iot api 200ok response]

Now what i do from app side?I think its permission issue but not able to resolved please suggest.

also attached code as follows:-

```
Interceptor interceptor = new Interceptor() {
@Override
public okhttp3.Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
Request newRequest = chain.request()
.newBuilder()
.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
.addHeader("host", "ag7fce49bf5ti.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com")
.addHeader("x-amz-date", "20160919T054450Z")
.addHeader("authorization", "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAJ6XB3CLURFLV6ISQ/20160919/us-east-1/iotdata/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=af7cd8cee7dd4763cff3a1c8f91cdde1fa22cc68012248a694cee098981bc623")
.build();
return chain.proceed(newRequest);
}
};

    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    builder.interceptors().add(interceptor);
    client = builder.build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://ag7fce49bf5ti.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/things/dm_project/shadow/")
            //.addConverterFactory(client)
            .client(client)
            .build();
```

Comment: post some code , where you are fetching the request.

Comment: actually i am not getting any error on particular line but my response from server side returns forbidden.

Comment: i think 404 is not found, 403 is forbidden. You are getting 404 or forbidden?

Comment: @SaurabhKataria:- Sorry Its my typing mistake got 403(forbidden).

Comment: So forbidden is basically that this user doesn't have access for this api.

Comment: Yes..But it gives me 200ok in response when i hit it from postman.

Comment: see if this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30461420/how-to-handle-auth0-403-error-without-adding-specific-code-everywhere-retrofit

Comment: @SaurabhKataria:- as per link provided Its for auth0 not for aws-iot so its diffrent.protocol is same but still there is problem.

Comment: can you post your request code , that might help in recognising the error. I tried but couldn`t replicate your scenario.

Comment: @SaurabhKataria:- please check my code as i attached in this question

Comment: Refer my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42106050/578309) to see if helpful