# Request working fine in postman, but getting a 403 in OkHTTP

Tags: java, rest, api, okhttp

I'm trying to make a request to the [Genius API](https://docs.genius.com), but I'm running into some issues using OkHTTP. This is my small script I'm using to make the call:

```
public class OkHttpScript {

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String run(String url) throws IOException {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer uDtfeAgTKL3_YnOxco4NV6B-WVZAIGyuzgH6Yp07FiV9K9ZRFOAa3r3YoxHVG1Gg")
            .url(url)
            .build();

    try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
        return response.body().string();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    OkHttpScript okHttpScript = new OkHttpScript();

    String response = okHttpScript.run("http://api.genius.com/songs/378195/");

    System.out.println(response);
}


}
```

When I run this script, I get a 403 error:

```
{"meta":{"status":401,"message":"This call requires an access_token. Please see: https://genius.com/developers"}}
```

For reference, here is a picture of me making the same exact request with Postman, and it works:

[image: Postman picture]

Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Edit:

Not sure if this is normal, but when I print out my request object that gets built, I see no indication that there are headers in the request:

```
Request{method=GET, url=http://api.genius.com/songs/378195/, tag=null}
```

Is what I get. Could this be part of the problem?

Edit2:

Nevermind, doing a

```
System.out.println(newRequest.headers());
```

gives me what I originally put in:

```
Authorization: Bearer 4mfDBVzCnp2S1Fc0l0K0cfqOrQYjRrb-OHi8W1f-PPU7LNLI6-cXY2E727-1gHYR
```

Comment: Try using Wireshark to see how the actual HTTP request is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out what my problem was. I'm not sure of the details behind it, but I should have been using my URL has `https://api.genius.com/songs/378195/` instead of `http://api.genius.com/songs/378195/`

Postman seems fine with the http, but OkHttp needed https.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how your server side is written, I had the same problem today when requesting someone else's service. My solution was to change the User-Agent, even if PostmanRuntime/7.26.10

Comment: NIce Hint though.

Answer (score -1):

You should add an interceptor for okhttp something like this should work

[How to handle auth0 403 error without adding specific code everywhere (Retrofit/okhttp/RxAndroid)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30461420/how-to-handle-auth0-403-error-without-adding-specific-code-everywhere-retrofit)

Comment: Doesn't that just re-do the call when it fails? Would writing an interceptor help me if I don't have some token that I need to refresh? The token itself remains static in my case.

Comment: Whether or not it’s an interceptor doesn’t explain why this request isn’t succeeding.

Answer (score -1):

*Used Alex Hermstad Answer

--> Use https instead of http in android ,
Postman seems fine with the http, but OkHttp needed https.

I was stuck for a day for this error 403 forbidden in android , but giving 200 success in Postman .

Comment: @JulianoMacedo I was having the same problem as asked in this question, so i tried to answer when i got the solution .Alex Hermstad has answered it first but to reach tis answer more i mentioned his name and also post this answer